# What's the equivalent of Ruby's class @@variable in Python?

Tags: python, ruby, class-variables

In Ruby 1.9, I can use its class variable like the following:

```
class Sample
  @@count = 0

  def initialize
    @@count += 1
  end

  def count
    @@count
  end
end

sample = Sample.new
puts sample.count     # Output: 1

sample2 = Sample.new
puts sample2.count    # Output: 2
```

How can I achieve the above in Python 2.5+ ?

Comment: You might want to precise if you want the same behavior as a class variable, or an instance variable of the singleton class (`class << Sample; attr_accessor :count; end`). The first one is shared between Sample and any subclass, while the later will be distinct for Sample and the subclass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Sample(object):
  _count = 0

  def __init__(self):
    Sample._count += 1

  @property
  def count(self):
    return Sample._count
```

The use is a bit different from Ruby; e.g. if you have this code in module `a.py`,

```
>>> import a
>>> x = a.Sample()
>>> print x.count
1
>>> y = a.Sample()
>>> print x.count
2
```

having a Sample.count "class property" (with the same name as the *instance* property) would be a bit tricky in Python (feasible, but not worth the bother IMHO).